# Regex that matches anything after text that is not a space

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex that returns TRUE or FALSE in the following cases:

```
# Returns TRUE
'Apples: 1'
'Apples: are a fruit'
'Apples: z'
'Apples: I don't care what comes here if it's not only spaces or nothing'

# Returns FALSE
'Apples:'
'Apples:  '
'Apples:     '
```

What I tried so far comes close, but I can't seem to cover the second part:

```
'Apples: ' -match '^Apples:[A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

The only thing is, there needs to be something coming after the `Apples:`, that cannot be a space or blanks. But there cam be some spaces first or after, but there does need to be text or a numerical value on the line.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
^Apples: *[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Where:

- `*` means *zero or more* spaces
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` means *one or more* characters of type `A-Za-z0-9`

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work:

```
'^Apples:\s*\S+\s*'
```

That will match if there is one or more non-whitespace characters following "Apple:", which may or may not have leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is perfect! Can you explain what `\S+` means?

Comment: @DarkLite1 `\S` is not space. `+` is one or more

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a match/nomatch result you could simply match on a colon followed by any number of whitespace and at least one non-whitespace character (`:\s*\S`).

```
PS C:\> 'Apples:' -match ':\s*\S'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples: ' -match ':\s*\S'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples:  ' -match ':\s*\S'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples: are a fruit' -match ':\s*\S'
True
PS C:\> 'Apples:x' -match ':\s*\S'
True
```

If you want to be able to extract the rest of the line you may want to use a lookbehind assertion for anchoring the match after a colon folowed by any number of whitespace characters (`(?<=:\s*)\S.*`).

```
PS C:\> 'Apples:' -match '(?<=:\s*)\S.*'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples: ' -match '(?<=:\s*)\S.*'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples:  ' -match '(?<=:\s*)\S.*'
False
PS C:\> 'Apples: are a fruit' -match '(?<=:\s*)\S.*'
True
PS C:\> $matches[0]
are a fruit
PS C:\> 'Apples:x' -match '(?<=:\s*)\S.*'
True
PS C:\> $matches[0]
x
```

Comment: Thx Ansgar, but then this doesn't match `'Apples:a' -match '^Apples: \S'`. So it's not necessary to have a space directly after, but it can be there.

Comment: @DarkLite1 You should've made that clear in your examples. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex metacharacter `\w` to match any word characters:

```
$Apples = 'Apples: 1','Apples: are a fruit','Apples: z','Apples:','Apples:  ','Apples:     '

$Apples | ForEach {$_ -match '^Apples: \w' }
```

Returns:

```
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

**Explanation:**

> The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character.
>
> A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _
>   (underscore) character.
>
> - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is in Python but should do the trick.  The regex is saying:
Must start with Apples:, then a space, then a NON-Space.  You could also use \w instead of \S but that won't catch &*%$ type characters.  Your call :)  Hope that helps!

```
import re


thelist = ['Apples: 1', 'Apples: are a fruit', 'Apples: z', 'Apples: I dont care what comes here if its not only spaces or nothing', 'Apples:', 'Apples:  ', 'Apples:     ']
theregex = "^Apples:\s\S"

for word in thelist:
    if re.search(theregex, word):
        print ("Hurrah, it's true")
    else:
        print ("Welcome to false town")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually capture the value of Apples in the match, this regex works:

`^Apples:\s*(.*\S.*)\s*`

It captures the value in match group 1.

Answer (score -1):

If you need slightly more general solution (not only *Apples*), try something like this:

```
/^[A-Z]+: *\K\w.*/gmi
```

How it works:

- `^[A-Z]+:` - Start of a **line** (note *m* switch),
  a sequence of letters (upper or lower case - note *i* switch).
- `*` - There can be some spaces.
- `\K` - *Keep* - "forget" what you matched till now, set the starting point
  of the match here.
- `\w.*` - A word char and possibly some number of any chars.
- *g* switch - to catch findings from all source rows.

The text actually matched is **only** what was after *\K*.

Comment: `\K` isn't available in PowerShell (.Net) regex dialect.